# how to solve an nth derivative for the equation $\ln((1+x)/(1-x))$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I'm trying to find the $n$th derivative of this function. 
I've got that the first term is:

$$ \frac{2(n!)x^{n-1}}{(x^2-1)^n} $$

Any improvement on this would be very helpful.

Comment: "Equation" is the wrong word here. $\qquad$

Comment: How about splitting the $ln$ term into two separate $ln$ terms by the properties of logarithms?

Comment: The $n-$th derivative in general or $f^{(n)}(0)$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$

So its first derivative is $(1+x)^{-1}+(1-x)^{-1}$. Because differentiation is linear, it suffices to compute the successive derivatives of each of the summands which can be computed using the power rule and chain rule.